# Linux: command to make folders recursively writable without affecting the permission of files inside them

Tags: linux, command-line, cmd, chmod

Is it possible to make the folders writable recursively without affecting the files inside them using Linux command.

`chmod 777 -R foldername` - will make all folders and files inside the folder writable.

We've a website where we do not want the core files of a php framework writable, but at the same time we should be able to add new files.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can say:

```
find foldername -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

This would only change the file mode for the *directories* and not the *files* within those.